# Snap is not updating

Tags: software-installation, updates, 22.04, snap, chromium

ubuntu 22.04. i'm updating all the snaps (`snap refresh`), but it still shows that chromium needs to be updated (snap refresh --list) and in fact the snap was not updated:

```
jojo@work:~$ sudo snap refresh
All snaps up to date.
jojo@work:~$ snap refresh --list
Name      Version         Rev   Size   Publisher   Notes
chromium  108.0.5359.124  2254  154MB  canonical✓  -
jojo@work:~$ snap info chromium
name:      chromium
summary:   Chromium web browser, open-source version of Chrome
publisher: Canonical✓
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/chromium
contact:   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bugs?field.tag=snap
license:   unset
description: |
  An open-source browser project that aims to build a safer, faster, and more
  stable way for all Internet users to experience the web.
commands:
  - chromium.chromedriver
  - chromium
snap-id:      XKEcBqPM06H1Z7zGOdG5fbICuf8NWK5R
tracking:     latest/stable
refresh-date: 4 days ago, at 22:02 CET
channels:
  latest/stable:    108.0.5359.124 2022-12-14 (2254) 154MB -
  latest/candidate: 108.0.5359.124 2022-12-14 (2254) 154MB -
  latest/beta:      109.0.5414.36  2022-12-09 (2247) 155MB -
  latest/edge:      110.0.5464.2   2022-12-12 (2250) 155MB -
installed:          108.0.5359.94             (2238) 153MB -
```

so the installed is xxx.94 and latest/stable is xxx.124

why the snap is not updated and how to actually update it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to update chromium:

```
sudo snap refresh chromium
```

or

```
sudo snap refresh chromium --channel=latest/stable
```

Comment: when i did `sudo snap refresh chromium` i finally got an error message: `error: cannot refresh "chromium": snap "chromium" has running apps (chromium), pids:`. so after i closed the app and manually triggered the update all went well